# ionic build ios --release failed

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, build

I'm newer here and i would like a help from you. My english is not very well, but i'm trying to explain my issue.

When i run the ionic build ios --release on my ionic app, and the temrinal shows the below error:

```
    ionic build ios --release

Running 'build:before' npm script before build
> ionic-hello-world@ build /Users/allanbarbosa/Projetos/mobi-unidadedigital/v3
> ionic-app-scripts build
[15:37:26]  ionic-app-scripts 0.0.28
[15:37:26]  build prod started ...
[15:37:26]  clean started ...
[15:37:27]  clean finished in 62 ms
[15:37:27]  copy started ...
[15:37:27]  ngc started ...
[15:37:27]  lint started ...
[15:37:27]  copy finished in 593 ms
[15:37:32]  lint finished in 5.18 s
[15:37:51]  ngc error: Error: Error at /Users/allanbarbosa/Projetos/mobi-unidadedigital/v3/.tmp/pages/ConsultantChat/consultant-chat.ngfactory.ts:432:42: Property 'cleanFilter' does not exist on type 'ConsultantChat'.
Error at /Users/allanbarbosa/Projetos/mobi-unidadedigital/v3/.tmp/pages/Estatisticas/components/PointsResume/points-resume.ngfactory.ts:552:40: Property 'accordeon' is private and only accessible within class 'PointsResume'.
Error at /Users/allanbarbosa/Projetos/mobi-unidadedigital/v3/.tmp/pages/Estatisticas/components/PointsResume/points-resume.ngfactory.ts:557:40: Property 'animaAccordeon' is private and only accessible within class 'PointsResume'.
Error at /Users/allanbarbosa/Projetos/mobi-unidadedigital/v3/.tmp/pages/Estatisticas/components/PointsResume/points-resume.ngfactory.ts:562:40: Property 'accordeon' is private and only accessible within class 'PointsResume'.
Error at /Users/allanbarbosa/Projetos/mobi-unidadedigital/v3/.tmp/pages/Estatisticas/components/PointsResume/points-resume.ngfactory.ts:567:45: Property 'accordeon' is private and only accessible within class 'PointsResume'.
Error at /Users/allanbarbosa/Projetos/mobi-unidadedigital/v3/.tmp/pages/Estatisticas/estatistica.ngfactory.ts:552:42: Property 'ConsultantChat' does not exist on type 'EstatisticaPage'.
Error at /Users/allanbarbosa/Projetos/mobi-unidadedigital/v3/.tmp/pages/ModalAccount/modal-account.ngfactory.ts:325:29: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
    at check (/Users/allanbarbosa/Projetos/mobi-unidadedigital/v3/node_modules/@angular/tsc-wrapped/src/tsc.js:31:15)
    at Tsc.typeCheck (/Users/allanbarbosa/Projetos/mobi-unidadedigital/v3/node_modules/@angular/tsc-wrapped/src/tsc.js:86:9)
    at /Users/allanbarbosa/Projetos/mobi-unidadedigital/v3/node_modules/@angular/tsc-wrapped/src/main.js:33:23
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:577:11)
    at startup (node.js:160:18)
    at node.js:456:3


[15:37:51]  ngc error: Compilation failed


[15:37:51]  ngc failed:  NGC encountered an error

[15:37:51]  Error: NGC encountered an error
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/allanbarbosa/Projetos/mobi-unidadedigital/v3/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/ngc.js:60:24)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:852:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:323:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:492:12)

Error running ionic app script "build": Error: NGC encountered an error



npm
 ERR! Darwin 16.1.0
npm
 ERR! argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/6.2.1/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "build"
npm ERR!
 node v6.2.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR!
 ionic-hello-world@ build: `ionic-app-scripts build`
npm ERR!
 Exit status 1

npm ERR!

npm ERR!
 Failed at the ionic-hello-world@ build script 'ionic-app-scripts build'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the ionic-hello-world package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     ionic-app-scripts build
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs ionic-hello-world
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls ionic-hello-world
npm
 ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.



npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!
     /Users/allanbarbosa/Projetos/mobi-unidadedigital/v3/npm-debug.log

Caught exception:
 undefined
```

I trying to search on my pages this ngc problems, but no successful. Someone can help me?

My ionic info

Your system information:

```
Cordova CLI: 6.4.0
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.1
Gulp local:
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.0
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.0-beta.1
ios-deploy version: 1.9.0
ios-sim version: 5.0.8
OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v6.2.1
Xcode version: Xcode 8.1 Build version 8B62
```

Comment: I'd start with the first error - Property 'cleanFilter' does not exist on type 'ConsultantChat'.  What does your ConsultantChat type look like? Does it have a function/property on it called cleanFilter?

Comment: Hello @SteveKennedy I search for cleanFilter on my .ts archive and don't find any match.

Comment: The code in your consultant-chat.ngfactory.ts is calling a cleanFilter property/method on your ConsultantChat type.  That's the first problem.  Why does your consultant-chat.ngfactory.ts code call a method/property that doesn't exist on your ConsultantChat type.

Comment: Already find the error. This variables was in HTML archive. Thank you!